# Regex exclude everything but, individually

Tags: php, regex, select

Current Regex:

```
([^ipd])
```

I get the correct output, although it doesn't deselect them individually. I'm wanting to deselect only `i`, `p` and `d` individually.

Want:

```
i
p
d
```

Don't want:

```
ipd
ip
pd
id
```

*etc.*

I've tried:

```
([^ipd] {1})
([^i|p|d$])
```

Comment: Maybe just: `([ipd])`

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking to capture the characters `i`, `p`, `d` in longer strings? E.g. as in [`([ipd])`](https://regex101.com/r/pD5vN6/1)? Note that you do not have to set a capturing group in this case as you will always be able to refer to the 0th group with `\0`. You need to clarify what you need in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant **deselect**

Comment: So, [`^(?![ipd]$)[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pD5vN6/2)?

Comment: Do you mean this? _https://regex101.com/r/pD5vN6/3_

Comment: If the string is `12ipd3ipdi` what's your expected output?

Comment: please, provide examples of initial lines and respective resulting matches

Answer (score 0):

```
^[ipd]$
```

You need to add anchors to limit the matches to just `i,p,d`.

```
$re = "/^[ipd]$/m"; 
$str = "i\np\nd\n\nDon't Want\nipd\nip\npd\nid"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: `^[ipd]$` didn't work for me. I'm just needing to select one at a time.

Comment: @Rahul Maybe there are other characters in your string (trailing spaces for example). In this case, use ^[ipd]\s*$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

This work in string and with separate characters:

```
[^ipd]|(?<=[ipd])[ipd]|[ipd](?=[ipd])
```

where:

- `[^ipd]` - not "i","p" or "d";
- `(?<=[ipd])[ipd]` - match "i","p" or "d" if it is proceeded by
  "i","p" or "d";
- `[ipd](?=[ipd])` - "i","p" or "d" if it is fallowed by "i","p" or
  "d";

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iR9yS5/2)